# HTML CSS remove div's property inherited from parents

Tags: html, css

I am totally new to web. I am trying some sample websites.

Now I am stuck in a div where I want a particular div to align left while other sibling divs are acquiring property of center aligned from the parent div.

Can anyone help me regarding removing property of the particular div and adding a new property?

Comment: What have you tried already? can you put what you have in a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: could you please post both your html and css code

Comment: if you will add a little details like what is your stylesheet or create a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks for the support. I solved the problem by using div id for the particular div and added property in the css. Rest divs were in a class.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to work with the actual code that you are working with. But essentially, this is just a basic fundamental knowledge of working with `padding`, `margin:0 auto;`, and `float`.

Here is an example of a div pushed to the left while the centered boxes are centered
[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/24sRL/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For suppose if you have given `float: left;` for the first then remaining div's will automatically sit beside them depending on the `width` of your element .To remove this you have to use `clear` property in CSS.